# Clearing a polyline on a Polymer Google Map

Tags: google-maps, polymer

**Case:** You enter 2 cities on a form and submit ; the Google Map gets the coordinates and 2 markers will appear (one for each city) with a polyline connecting those markers. When there is a new submit with another cities, I want the markers and the polyline to be replaced to match the new coordinates.

**Problem:** When I submit a first search, everything is fine, coordinates are obtained and markers + polyline are drawn. When I submit another search, the markers are replaced, but not the polyline.

- I don't have any JS written yet, trying to use Polymer at its best (maybe that's a mistake, but then why does it work with the markers and not the polyline?) ;
- All imports (Polymer elements and custom elements) are made and no files is missing ;
- There is no error displayed in the console at any time ;
- I also tried to use the `clear()` method provided by the API on the `<google-map>` element, without any result (I guess my custom elements are not considered as a part of the map) ;
- I **do not** want to display multiple polylines or multiple couples of markers, I just want to clear/replace the first ones when another search is made ;
- It works well when I just clear the array in the console with `markersPolyline.markers = []` and then submit a new search.

What's wrong with the code? Did I misunderstood the data-binding? Is it my way to use Polymer which is wrong?

---

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <template is="dom-bind">
        <google-map latitude="39.639538" longitude="6.328125" zoom="3" api-key="…" disable-default-ui>
            <distance-search from-city="Paris, France" to-city="NYC, USA"></distance-search>
            <markers-cities></markers-cities>
            <markers-polyline></markers-polyline>
        </google-map>
    </template>
</body>
```

`<distance-search>` is my custom element displaying a form with two cities (pre-filled for demo purposes). The cities are geocoded by a call to the Google Maps API and an array is returned. Nothing seems to be wrong on that side, the geocoding and the array returned works well.

`<markers-cities>` is my custom element which will display the markers on the right coordinates (based on what's returned by the *distance-search* element).

`<markers-polyline>` is my custom element which will draw a polyline from the first marker to the second one (based on what's returned by the *distance-search* element).

**distance-search.html (JS only)**

*No need to put all the code here: the AJAX calls works well. I only store the result in 2 arrays and send them to my custom elements*

```
<script>
Polymer({

    is: 'distance-search',

   /** triggered wen the AJAX returns something **/
    _onResponseRetrieved: function(event) {
        var coords = event.detail.response,
            markersCities = document.querySelector('markers-cities'),
            markersPolyline = document.querySelector('markers-polyline');

        markersPolyline.markers =
        markersCities.markers =
        [
            {
                "lat": coords.lat1,
                "lng": coords.lng1
            }, {
                "lat": coords.lat2,
                "lng": coords.lng2
            }
        ];
    }

});
</script>
```

**markers-cities.html**

```
<dom-module id="markers-cities">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{markers}}" as="marker">
            <google-map-marker map="{{map}}" latitude="{{marker.lat}}" longitude="{{marker.lng}}"></google-map-marker>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'markers-cities',
            properties: {
                markers : {
                    type: Array
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**markers-polyline.html**

```
<dom-module id="markers-polyline">
    <template>
        <google-map-poly map="{{map}}" stroke-color="#FF0000" stroke-opacity="0.5" geodesic>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{markers}}" as="marker">
                <google-map-point latitude="{{marker.lat}}" longitude="{{marker.lng}}"></google-map-point>
            </template>
        </google-map-poly>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'markers-polyline',
            properties: {
                markers : {
                    type: Array
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data binding in `<markers-polyline>` looks correct to me. It's possibly a bug (similar to [issue #299](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/299)) that you might want to report in GitHub.

> It works well when I just clear the array in the console with `markersPolyline.markers = []` and then submit a new search.

Using this clue, I was able to implement a workaround that clears the `markers` and then sets a new array value at the end of the microtask (with [`Polymer.Base.async`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#async-and-debounce)).

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map-marker.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map-poly.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map-point.html">
</head>
<body unresolved>
<style>
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<x-foo></x-foo>

<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style>
      google-map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      paper-button {
        background: red;
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
      }
    </style>

    <google-map zoom="8"
                latitude="37.77493"
                longitude="-122.41942"
                fit-to-markers
                api-key="AIzaSyCjhMOhRrvFgImADyUqAAaEsZAC9SP_TNc">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[markers]]" as="marker">
        <google-map-marker latitude="[[marker.lat]]" longitude="[[marker.lng]]"></google-map-marker>
      </template>
      <google-map-poly closed fill-color="blue" fill-opacity=".5">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[markers]]" as="marker">
          <google-map-point latitude="[[marker.lat]]" longitude="[[marker.lng]]"></google-map-point>
        </template>
      </google-map-poly>
    </google-map>

    <paper-button on-tap="updatePolyline">Update Polyline</paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-foo',

      properties: {
        markers: {
          type: Array
        }
      },

      ready: function() {
        this.markers = [
          { lat: 36.77493, lng: -121.41942 },
          { lat: 38.77493, lng: -122.41942 },
          { lat: 36.77493, lng: -123.41942 }
        ];
      },

      updatePolyline: function() {
        var m = this.markers.slice(0, 2);
        this.setMarkers([
          { lat: m[0].lat + 0.05, lng: m[0].lng },
          { lat: m[1].lat - 0.05, lng: m[1].lng }
        ]);
      },

      setMarkers: function(markers) {
        this.markers = [];
        this.async(function() {
          this.markers = markers;
        });
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VKpqQJ?editors=1000)

> why does it work with the markers and not the polyline?

The observers for `<google-map-marker>` and `<google-map-point>` are implemented differently, which might be why they don't behave exactly the same.

The container of the `<google-map-point>`s (i.e., `<google-map-poly>`) [uses a `MutationObserver` to detect when map-points are added/removed](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/a4d9bfc/google-map-poly.html#L473), at which point it rebuilds the polygon path.

On the other hand, the container of the `<google-map-marker>`s (i.e., `<google-map>`) [observes changes to its `<iron-selector>.items`](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/a4d9bfc/google-map.html#L511) (which contains the markers).

Comment: Indeed, the bug looks exactly like mine. I will upvote this bug by posting in. Thanks for the detailed answer and the workaround!